# Resizing height and width with Percentage instead of pixels in a Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm just wondering how I can make a Javascript Canvas responsive with 90% in height and 100% in width. I have tried:

```
canvas.width = 100%;
canvas.height = 90%;
```

However it just brings up syntax errors in my IDE and the canvas no longer renders.
Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretch-when-using-css-but-normal-with-old-width-and-height-proper    AND      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750125/scaling-html5-canvas-width-preserving-w-h-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `canvas.style.width = '100%';` and similarly for `height`.