# Setting Canvas size with JQuery blurs contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I've got a simple resize script as such:

```
$(`#game`).css('width', '100%');

$(window).resize(function(){
    $(`#game`).height($(`#game`).width() / 2.031);
})
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10750346/12359120)

The problem though, as *cyberwombat* said,
"This will cause the content to be blurred."

The other answers on that post don't really work for my situation, as they often make the contents go offscreen.

Right now this is how blurry it is:
[image: The canvas being blurry on a large screen]
With the other answers:
[image: The canvas going off the screen vertically]

Is there any way to make it less blurry?

Edit: The element's width and height always say 300 and 150 even though the styles say otherwise. Here is some HTML + CSS + JS that can mostly reproduce this.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('game')
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

$(`#game`).css('width', '100%');

$(window).resize(function() {
  $(`#game`).height($(`#game`).width() / 2.031);
})

const imageAt = ((href, x, y, sizex, sizey) => {
  var img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, sizex, sizey);
  }, false);
  img.src = href
})
imageAt('https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/bZedgr0gq7RQBBnVYVc-Nmzdr-5vEUg4Dj8nTrMb7yA.png',0,0,25,25)
```

```css
#game {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

#vertical-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="vertical-center">
  <canvas id="game"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to redraw the canvas. It won't automatically do it itself.

Comment: I'm drawing the images on the canvas after it's resized. Is there some function to redraw it that I should know about? @Andy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 - Canvas, drawImage() draws image blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910043/html5-canvas-drawimage-draws-image-blurry)

Comment: @Greedo it makes it kinda worse. https://i.ibb.co/sgY22BF/image.png

Comment: I assume the image is in a rasterised format, therefore any attempt to resize it (especially making it larger) will result in a loss of quality.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm not looking to make it bigger, it fits the entire page perfectly on all devices. The blurriness of when I draw anything into it is my issue. The element's width and height always say `300` and `150` even though the styles say otherwise.

Comment: Ok, understood. Can you please edit the question to include your relevant HTML & CSS so we can create a working example of the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Will do, hold on.